# Php PDO loop a resource instead of fetch

Tags: php, mysql, azure, pdo

I have been searching the internet and this forum, but I still can't figure out a good way for doing it FAST and specially without running into memory usage issues. Here goes my task:

What I did in traditional mysql:

I have 3 tables, lets say: table1, table2, and table3
Let's assume that table1 has 300.000 rows (they are purchase items, for example)
Let's assume that table2 is the list of products, and has 10.000 rows
Let's assume that table 3 is the services lists, with also 10.000 rows

Now, what I need to do is generate a report listing every purchase in a loop, which will check if the the purchase item is for a product or a service, and if it is a product it will output the name of the product by getting the correspondent name column on the table2. The same would happen if it is a service...

1) In the manuals and forums it's said that I cannot run another query in PDO without finishing reading all my rows... which is this case as I need to run another query to get the name of the product/service. (In mysql this is pretty simple as I can handle many result resources and just iterate between them with mysql_result)

2) Some people said that using fetchall or even fetch would explode my memory usage and I would not be able to do this query....I already tried getting a an array with all the results (300K) and it figuratively explodes the memory usage of my server...

So guys can you help me? I am trying to move my servers to windows azure and they only allow pdo os sqlsrv.....

Ok as some people have asked here goes my theoretical code:

```
// connect to mysql database
$sql = @mysql_connect("{server}","{login}","{password}");
@mysql_select_db("{database}");

// query:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY purchase_date ASC");

for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){

   if(mysql_result($result,$i,"purchase_type")==1){

         $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT product_name FROM table2 WHERE id='".mysql_result($result,$i,"purchase_type_id")."'");       
         $name = mysql_result($result1,0,"product_name");

   }else if(mysql_result($result,$i,"purchase_type")==2){

         $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT service_name FROM table3 WHERE id='".mysql_result($result,$i,"purchase_type_id")."'"); 
         $name = mysql_result($result1,0,"service_name");

   }else{

         $name = '{error}';
   }

   echo(($i+1)". ".$name." <br/>");

}
```

PS: This is just an example code....the real code is by far longer and more complex than that.... But if I can solve the theory here I can figure out the rest... :)

PS2: Before someone asks.... table2 and table3 have different columns....

Thanks,

Comment: post your code and queries, this will make it easier for us to answer.

Comment: Post the structure of your tables. If there are properly designed relationships between them you should be able to use `JOIN` and get all the information you need in just one query / result set.

Comment: Joining values between tables should be done in the database, not in the script. It will be very slow to keep packaging up and sending off queries. It is trivial to have your query do something like: case when type='service' then service.name else product.name end as itemname

Comment: Let's say I cannot JOIN them....just to have an idea, they can be in different physical locations/servers...even in different continents....so no join possible.... I know this is slow...but this is not the point of the question.... hope you guys can understand.... :)

Comment: By the way...another question: how do you make a JOIN with conditional statements like the one in my code? Is it possible?

Comment: Added an answer which would the `JOIN`, however, if it's in separated databases and no `JOIN` is possible, there would also be separate db-connections, and hence no problem in having to fetch all results from one connection before another query, because the other query is going over another connection, so you can safely leave the first resultset in the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  table1.*,
  COALESCE(table2.product_name, table3.service_name, '{error}') as name
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
  ON table1.purchase_type = 1
  AND table2.id = table1.purchase_type_id
LEFT JOIN table3 
  ON table1.purchase_type = 2
  AND table3.id = table1.purchase_type_id
ORDER BY table1.purchase_date
```

Note that by letting `purchase_type_id` refer to either table2 or table3 you miss some advantages from foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (hopefully it works, I made it up as I went along):

```
<?php
// connect to SQLserv database with PDO
$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=yourServer; Database=yourDB", "user", "password");

$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY purchase_date ASC");
$statement->execute();
$main_result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$statement->closeCursor();
unset($statement);

$p_type1 = array();
$p_type2 = array();

foreach ($main_result as $row => $column) {
    switch ($column["purchase_type"]) {
        case 1:
            $p_type1[] = $column["purchase_type_id"];
            break;
        case 2:
            $p_type2[] = $column["purchase_type_id"];
            break;
    }
}

$names = array();

$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT product_name FROM table2 WHERE id = :id");
foreach ($p_type1 as $value) {
    $statement->execute(":id" => $value);
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $statement->closeCursor();
    $names[] = $result[0]["product_name"];
}
unset($statement);
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT service_name FROM table3 WHERE id = :id");
foreach ($p_type2 as $value) {
    $statement->execute(":id" => $value);
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $statement->closeCursor();
    $names[] = $result[0]["service_name"];
}

foreach ($names as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key. $value<br />\n";
}
?>
```